# Making a custom collection in shopify liquid - liquid

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to make a custom collection in collection.liquid based on some conditional scenario and for this I applied `concat`, `append` and `join` but the problem is that it returns `ProductDropProductDropProductDropProductDrop...` or `LazyProductDropCollectionLazyProductDropCollection` instead of products. Following is the code snippet

```
{% assign custom_products = '' %}
{% for product in collections["paneer-easy-indie-bowls"].products %}
  {% assign custom_products = custom_products | append: product %}
{% endfor %}
```

instead of append I tried both `join` and `concat` but returns `ProductDropProductDropProductDropProductDrop...`

```
{% assign custom_products = custom_products | concat: product %}
```

then I tried the following:

```
{% capture custom_products %}
  {% for product in collections["paneer-easy-indie-bowls"].products %}
    {{ custom_products }},{{ product.handle }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign custom_products = custom_products | split: ',' %}

{% for product in custom_products %}
  {{ product}}
{% endfor %}
```

but this code not appending the products in right way. I want products like same as`{{collection.products}}`. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use these string filters with Liquid objects.
It would be best if you could create a collection that holds all these custom products.
But if the custom products you want are not related in any way, and are too many to manually add to a new collection,

- You could try looping on each collection and render HTML for each iteration.
  You could use if/unless statements or the "where" filter to filter the products inside the iterations.
- If you’re trying to achieve something more complicated,
  consider creating a Javascript object using the same Liquid iterations.
  For example:

```html
<script>
  const customProducts = [
    {% for product in collections['collection1'].products -%}
      {{ product | json }},
    {%- endfor %}
    {% for product in collections['collection2'].products -%}
      {{ product | json }},
    {%- endfor %}
    {% for product in collections['collection3'].products -%}
      {{ product | json }}{%- unless forloop.last -%},{%- endunless -%}
    {%- endfor %}
  ]
</script>
```

Then you could handle anything further with Javascript.
Of course this is less recommended, it would be best if you could handle everything using only Liquid and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your pseudo-code correctly, you are trying to build a collection of products from a collection of products. Which leads to the question, why? Since you already have a perfect collection, use it as is!

Comment: Hi @David Lazar, actually I have different collections and I need to pickup selected products from different collections and use it as a single object.

Comment: You might find it much easier to make a collection from rules that work for you then. Cherry picking products out of multiple collections with code is never fun.